# RoutePrefix is not registering routes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sitecore

We are developing in Sitecore CMS and we have noticed that randomly RoutePrefix attribute is ignore in Sitecore CMS dll file. So the first idea is that the whole dll file is not loaded, but this has been debugged and seen it is loaded through our custom code. Also when I haven't actually touched my local environment, I have noticed that one of the routes is suddenly working. I have developed other pieces of code and when deployed locally, it works sometimes and sometimes not, even when the code is completely unrelated to that. So its this CMS one of the dll file controller contains this RoutePrefix which is not loaded.

I have tried porbably everything with everyone, so this is my last place to ask for help, any ideas even how far its fetched? I have decompiled the Sitecore.ListManagement.Services.dll but came up nothing.

Support portal also have been tried to for a month to investigate our website folder content and haven't came up with a solution. This issue feels very random and it breaks or works